# stopping a postgres infinite recursive query

Tags: postgresql, unix, server, infinite-loop

i have written a wrong infinite-loop recursive query as i have been learning recursive postgres queries and affected the whole server postgres server

every database request takes inifinitely long time, giving me timeouts. so i have tried doing `/etc/init.d/postgresql` restart but while it seems to have helped a little, the postgres queries still run slowly

are the unfinished queries cached even after the postgtres server restart? how could i escape this sticky situation? :(

Comment: I can only guess, since I'm rather an Oracle guy, but restarting a database system the *hard* way, makes it doing a lot of cleanup-work during startup, so maybe postgreSQL is just busy cleaning up; probably not the stuff left behind by your query but other stuff.

Comment: I'd guess the server is still recovering from memory pressure condition - swapped out important memory. Reboot or `swapoff -a; swapon -a` can help.

Comment: thank you very much. it indeed runs fine now after a couple of minutes. could some of you please post the comment as an answer so i can mark it as correct? :)

Answer (score -1):

thank you ammoQ and Tometzky for your answers, it ended up the postgres process was cleaning up a lot of stuff. it gets back to normal after a couple of minutes